# Google Sheets custom function conditional formatting

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need to make a cell text turn red if the value of the cell is equal to the value of the cell two rows above it. I have these two functions in my script editor:

```js
/**
 * Compares cell value to another cell relative in position to it.
 * Returns true if equal values.
 *
 * @param {Number} colDiff Relative positioning column difference.
 * @param {Number} rowDiff Relative positioning row difference.
 */
function equalsRelativeCellValue(rowDiff, colDiff) {
  var thisCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var relativeCellValue = getRelativeCellValue(rowDiff, colDiff);
  if (thisCell.getValue() === relativeCellValue)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}


/**
 * Returns value of cell according to relative position
 *
 * @param {Number} colDiff Relative positioning column difference.
 * @param {Number} rowDiff Relative positioning row difference.
 */
function getRelativeCellValue(rowDiff, colDiff) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row + rowDiff,col + colDiff);
  return range2.getValue();
}
```

The second function, `getRelativeCellValue(rowDiff, colDiff)` works just fine, I put `8` in a cell, and two cells below it I entered `getRelativeCellValue(-2, 0)`, and the cell evaluated to `8`.

But the first function, `getRelativeCellValue(rowDiff, colDiff)` won't work as my custom function in conditional formatting for some reason:

```
Custom formula is: =equalsRelativeCellValue(-2,0)
```

The difficult part is referring to the value of the cell being referenced in the conditional formatting. But my function looks right to me, it returns `true` if the cell values are equal, and `false` if they are not. Im hoping I'm just using the "Custom formula is" feature of Conditional Formatting improperly, but the [documentation is pretty sparse](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just realizer what you want to do, just use conditional formatting, select the range, and apply for the first cell, and it will apply for all correctly:

Eg.
In conditional formating dialog, select Custom Formula, paste the custom formula `=J10=J8`, and select the range `J10:J100`.

OldAnswer:

You created a circular reference.

<s>If you input `=equalsRelativeCellValue(-2,0)` in the the Cell, how can it's value be anything, if it is waiting for the function to resolve?</s>

You can overcome this in a column besides the values, or pass the value directly in the function.

You can also use this to make the between cell have a true/false state:

```
function equalsRelativeCellValue(rowDiff, colDiff) {
  var below = getRelativeCellValue(1, 0);
  var relativeCellValue = getRelativeCellValue(2, 0);
  if (below === relativeCellValue)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, much simpler than what I was trying to do. Only thing is I cant seem to get this to work for multiple columns at a time. No big deal though, only had 5 cols to apply it to, so I wrote 5 different rules.

Comment: Got it to work in multiple columns using this range: `D4:D49,E4:E49,F4:F49,G4:G49` rather than `D4:G49`